# What is a point with nonsmooth boundary?

Tags: algorithm, sampling, random-walk

I am trying to implement the billiard walk sampling algorithm presented in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.3932.pdf.
One step of the algorithm is stating: 
 **"If a point with nonsmooth boundary is met or the number of reflections
exceeds R, go to step 3. Otherwise, proceed until the length of the
trajectory equals ℓ."**, but I have no clue what **"a point with nonsmooth boundary"** represents and I couldn't find much online.

Thank you very much.

Comment: "Smooth" in mathematics usually means "infinitely differentiable".  They mean a point where the boundary has a corner, or cusp, or some other irregularity that makes it impossible to define the normal direction.

Comment: They should probably have said "a point at which the boundary is not smooth".

Comment: Hi @NateEldredge, thank you for your reply. :)

Comment: If I sampler over a convex polytope, do I have to worry about this?

Comment: Section 3.1 explains this.  If you start from a randomly selected starting point, then the probability of ever hitting such a nonsmooth boundary point is zero.

Comment: I completely missed that :( Thank you very, very much!